# Login on Website will not work after some time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I build an internal website with user login/roles on IIS.

I use VS2017 and the website based on default ASP.net Webapplication project(web forms + master page + single user authentication).

All works good, until on point. After this it is no more possibly to login until I make a restart of the webserver.

The login itself work (I have a logging in it), but after the redirect from the login page to the start page the User.Identity is empty(in my menu bar it did not change from LOGIN to LOGOFF)

Has anybody an idea why this happen and how I can fix it.

My Login.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        var returnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            //RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl += "?ReturnUrl=" + returnUrl;
        }
    }

    protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Log.DebugFormat("Page IsValid: {0}",IsValid);
        if (IsValid)
        {
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            Log.InfoFormat("User {0} is Logging in",Email.Text);
            var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);
            Log.InfoFormat("Login Result: {0}",result);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                    break;
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");
                    break;
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}", 
                                                    Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
                                                    RememberMe.Checked),
                                      true);
                    break;
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    FailureText.Text = "Ungültiger Anmeldeversuch.";
                    ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

My Startup.Auth.cs

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    { 
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });
}
```

My Web.config

```
<configuration>
        <configSections>
            <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </configSections>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="packet size=4096;integrated security=false;data source=bpaw-gfxdb1;persist security info=false;initial catalog=ChannelPortWeb;Uid=sa;Pwd=ImagineDB1;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        </connectionStrings>  
        <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
         </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="1047552" />
        <pages>
         <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>

    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" />
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>

  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1" newVersion="4.0.2.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It appears the connection to server ended without user login off which often happens.  You software should be more robust so even though the user is still listed as login should be allowed to login again.

Comment: You mean I should logoff the user automatically before  Login?

Comment: But I have the same problem, if I you use an other login(that was not used long time) -> I will investigate this next time.

Comment: An Ethernet connection is terminated with one of following 1) Can be server was restarted 2) Software closed connection (it can be app or operating system) 3) Cable is disconnected.  The application may not get notified of the termination and will still have a status that user is logged in even tho the user is not logged in due to connection ended.